# ¿Como salgo de un menu de opciones con funciones en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!
Tengo un codigo donde tengo un menu dentro de ello mando a llamar las funciones, lo que pasa es que desde una funcion, por ejemplo "Mostrar recetas" quiero salir al inicio() pero no funciona correctamente, entra a inicio() pero se sigue ejecutando el menú == 1

Este es el menu:

```
final = False
while not final:

menu = inicio()
if menu == 1:
    mostrar_catego = mostrar_categorias(base)
    choose_catego = elegir_categoria(mostrar_catego)
    mis_recets = **mostrar_recetas**(choose_catego)
    choose_recet = elegir_receta(mis_recets)
    leer_recet(choose_recet)
    volver_inicio()
```

Esta es mi funcion mostrar recetas

```
def mostrar_recetas(ruta):
    categoria = Path(ruta)
    lista_recetas = []
    contador = 1
    if not len(os.listdir(categoria)):
        # if os.path.exists(categoria):
        print("No existen recetas")
        volver = input("¿Quieres crear una nueva receta? (s/n): ")
        while volver.lower() in 's':
            crear_receta(ruta)
            break
        else:
            volver = input("¿Quieres volver al menú? (s/n): ")
            while volver.lower() in 's':
                inicio()
                break
            else:
                sys.exit("Adios!")
    else:
        for n in categoria.glob('**/*.txt'):
            print("Estas son tus recetas:")
            receta_str = str(n.name)
            print(f"[{contador}] - {receta_str}")
            lista_recetas.append(n)
            contador += 1
            return lista_recetas
```

Comment: Comparto codigo para una mejor visualizacion...
https://pastebin.com/YfnfiD2A

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, después del primer bucle `while` el código nunca va a entrar al `else`, y por tanto no se va a ejecutar el método `inicio()`. Yo te diría que saques ese `else` y desindentes todo lo que hay adentro

Comment: Si pongo 'n' me envía a la siguiente, que si deseo volver al menú, si pongo 's' para que vaya a la función inicio lo hace, pero al momento de querer escoger de nuevo alguna opción del menú, sigue el programa desde el "choose_recet = elegir_receta(mis_recets)" y no regresa por completo

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo:

```
menu = int(input("1-Mostrar Carta \n 2-Mostrar Receta \n 3-Salir"))


while menu !=0:

   if menu==1:

      def mostrar_carta()

   if menu == 3:

       break
```

Disculpa por el desorden.